# Loading module from Template Toolkit fails

Tags: json, perl, catalyst

Using Perl 5.10, Catalyst, JSON 2.90.

On our production server when i `[% USE JSON %]` within a Template Toolkit, i get an error saying that the module cannot be found (I know it's installed).

Is this possibly a configuration issue? On other boxes in our office, the template loads without error.

Comment: What is the exact error message you get? Where does it appear (in the template output? in the Catalyst debug output?)

Comment: Which module do you know is installed?

Answer (score 4):

In Template Toolkit (TT) the code

`[% USE JSON %]`

does not load the Perl Module `JSON`. The TT command loads a TT Plugin. Your command tries to load the module [Template::Plugin::JSON](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Template::Plugin::JSON)

So, you also need to ensure that this plugin is installed, not just the `JSON` module.